# How to use one column in a Dataframe to divide one column in another DataFrame in Spark?(Use Python)

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have two DataFrame:
the one includes the total number of requests per day, called `total_req_per_day_df`，just like:

[image]

and the another DataFrame includes the number of unique hosts per day, called `daily_hosts_df`, just like

[image]

Now I want to use the total number of requests per day (across all hosts)  to divide the number of unique hosts per day to compute the average number of requests per host.How to programme in Spark with python?